# Can I print the file name and path when using a PDF uploader?

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload

I have wrote a simple PDF uploader in PHP. It works fine and the PDF uploads fine. However I would like to print the file name and the file path (where it is being saved). On the upload.php form. Is this possible?

upload.php

```
<form action="../pdf/upload_pdf2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="image"/>
    <label><?php echo strlen($filename ) > 0 ? $filename : "" ?> will be saved to /public_html/dev/pdf</label>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <input type="submit" class="upload-button"/>
</form>
```

upload_pdf2.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];   
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));
    $extensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png","pdf");      

    if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions )=== false){
        $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
    }

    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be excatly 2 MB';
    }

    if(empty($errors)==true){
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"../pdf/".$file_name);
        echo "File uploaded sucessfully";
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
?>
```